# Can I use DFS or a namespace to redirect the top level share e.g. \\server\redirect -> \\otherserver\share\some\path\

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing, share, smbfs

Let's say I have a share with a really long path. e.g. 
**\\targetserver\share\folder1\folder2\folderIWant**.

I can use DFS to get a shorter path, e.g. 
**\\server\shareFolder\folderIWant**

However, I was hoping to shorten it even further by getting rid of the "shareFolder" bit. e.g. 
**\\server\folderIWant**

Does anyone know if this is possible?